# php5-gd broken packages on debian 7.1 wheezy

Tags: php, debian, php-5.5

This is the error that is displayed when trying to install.

```
root@BH13:# apt-get install php5-gd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-gd : Depends: libt1-5 (>= 5.1.0) but it is not installable
           Depends: libvpx1 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

php version.

```
root@BH13:# php -v
PHP 5.5.38-1~dotdeb+7.1 (cli) (built: Jul 21 2016 18:33:48)
```

It does not let me install php5-gd to use the php image libraries.

This is in sources.list

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ squeeze-lts main contrib non-free
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php55 all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php55 all
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy all
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze all
```

This was the version of php that I had before updating:
PHP Version 5.4.45-0+deb7u9

and previous sources.list

```
deb http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
deb-src http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib
```

Thanks for the support.